# Choosing Presentation layer for spring application?

Tags: user-interface, jakarta-ee, spring-mvc, spring-webflow

i was using JSP and YUI with spring applications
and i want to use a new presentation layer like IceFaces or GWT or any other good one
but i am confused what to choose
i need to make a good looking view, and the technology must have a good support/samples, and easy to use, commonly used with spring, please advise, thanks.

Comment: I think you cannot expect a final answer to this very broad question. I'd start by listing all requirements and then compare all (some of) those framworks out there with each other, so that you are in a position to make a sound decision.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have enough experience in IceFaces, but GWT is really easy, rapid and full ajaxian. Also the SEO issues can be handled in GWT.

Answer (score 1):

Although a bit old, check out:-
http://woork.blogspot.com/2009/01/10-beautiful-web-ui-libraries.html